# Retrieve JSessionId in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, cookies, jira

I am currently developing a web application which runs on a tomcat. This web application needs to get access to a specific jira instance. On this instance a jsp is running which I can call like that:

```
String jiraURL = https://jiraurl.org/theJSP.jsp?timestamp=&__name=&__username=&__page&__target=&_sign_=;
```

I got all the different information to build up the URL String.
Then I load the page like so:

```
<html>
   <head>

       <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<%jiraURL%>"
   </head>
</html>
```

Via the page and target attribute the site referres then back to my web application. When i run it in chrome for example I can see that there is a cookie saved called `"JSESSIONID"` for `jiraurl.org`. This is the value I want to get in my jsp file, since I need this id to authenticate with the JIRA Rest API. I am currently using username/password, but I would like to authenticate via cookies.

Also you have to know that I have no access to change the `theJSP.jsp`.

So: **Is there anyway for me to retrieve the JSESSIONID from the other site which gets created when I run my HTTP-request ?**

Comment: Your question is unclear, but it sounds like you probably want to be [using OAuth](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+OAuth+authentication) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use JIRA REST API method /rest/auth/1/session: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e3737 to authenticate user and get JSESSIONID.

Comment: I logged in and then head to this url. This is all i get: `{"self":"someurl","name":"myusername","loginInfo":{"loginCount":1}}`. No Session Id. I looked into my browsers web console and the JSESSIONID is in the request header..

Comment: You need to login through this method passing json via POST:
{
    "username": "fred",
    "password": "freds_password"
}